# padding problems in content div

Tags: html, css

its rather hard to explain, when I search for something that isn't there, i am faced with a weird padding/margin issue and have checked the code and cant find anything. there appears to be a weird 30pxish margin after the footer which shouldnt even be in the content div.

```
<div class="post">
<div class="content">
<p>Sorry, no match found!</p>
</div>
</div>
<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

URL: http://s1527.mtchs.org/wordpress/?s=this+is+an+example+of+a+search+that+doesnt+exist

Comment: I have voted to close this question because it's too specific to your site, and unlikely to help any future visitors.  The best questions have a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code *directly* into the question. Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've also got some invalid HTML in there, there's a couple of div tags that you've opened, but not closed, this can make your CSS get messed up, I suggest regularly checking your code with the [W3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Answer (score 0):

"After the footer" is the closure of the `#postcont` element, which has 20px padding defined.
So it seems your css is not producing any anomalies seeing as it is defined and displaying as expected.

Comment: its not the post space, its the green space under the post

Comment: even then, the css looks like it is doing what it is told.